# Linq filter using List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a database with a column: Year (nvarchar) and I want to add the values of this column to a dropbox, sorted descending.

This is the code that I am using:

```
List<string>years = db.tbl1.Select(w => w.Year).Distinct().ToList();
years.reverse();
foreach (string year in years) { drop_years.Items.Add(year);}
```

It is not working because beeing a string I will have something like this: 2012, 2010, 2009, 2011, etc ..

If I use:

```
List<int> years = db.tbl1.Select(w => w.Year).Distinct().ToList();
```

the compiler tell me that cannot immplicitly convert type ..< string > to ..< int >...

I am a biginer and I do not know how to resolve this issue.
Could you please help me?

I serched about this but the similar topics with mine did not help me to figure out.

To manage my problem I used a very unprofessional method:

```
    var years = db.tbl1.Select(w => w.Year).Distinct();
    List<int> yearsList = new List<int>();
    foreach (string year in years)
    { yearsList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(year)); }
    yearsList.Sort(); //I used Sort() because doesn't work only with Reverse();
    yearsList.Reverse();
```

but I know that is not an elegant solution.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Reverse() just reverses the order it came out of the database. It's not ensured they will come out pre-sorted! You'd have to call SortBy or SortByDescending to get the order you want. Then do appropriate parse or cast. You almost had it!

Comment: " 2012, 2010, 2009, 2011" is not a string sorted list. It is as Erik says that you are just not getting it sorted from the database. Assuming all your years are four digit then you will be able to string sort them fine. Its only when you have differing numbers of digits that you get problems with string sorting numbers (eg 1, 10, 2, 3)

Comment: It looks like it's requested the type be specifically numeric (ints in this case), not string compares. If we knew the existing datatype in the database for Year and what the end type needs to be, we could be more explicit in the code example.

Comment: What UI framework are you using?  You should sort it as part of the UI layer.  In WPF you would use ICollectionView.

Comment: It is a project in Asp.Net F4.0. Thanks. I will consider that for WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is your first line changed to:

```
List<string>years = db.tbl1.Select(w => w.Year).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();
```

The addition of the order by will ensure that the content is sorted when it comes out the database, something that you are not otherwise doing.

More neatly you can use `OrderByDescending` and then omit the `Reverse` that you do later.

Assuming all your years are four digit then you will be able to string sort them fine. Its only when you have differing numbers of digits that you get problems with string sorting numbers (eg 1, 10, 2, 3). The reason is that if your numbers are all the same number of digits then each character compared will be of the same order of magnitude (eg thousands will always be compared to thousands).

Comment: Wow! :) Thank you very much. It's working. Now I need to look closer and "digest" all your helping responses.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers that were helpful to you (and to accept the final answer that you think best answers your question).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Sorry, but I am new here and I am not moving so well for the moment.

Comment: No need to apologise. I was only saying it because I could see you were new (low rep score) and thought you might not understand how these things work. :)

Comment: Ok :) Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points for the moment to vote. For me all the answers are helpful. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Select()` method and converting the Year (string) in `int`. Something like this:

```
var years = db.tbl1.Select(w => w.Year).Distinct().ToList().Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

It will execute a query on database, get a dinstinc and year column, after it, it will convert in memory (linq to objects) to a `IList<int>`. After it, `years` will be a `IList<int>` and you can use `Sort()` and other method for this type (or extensions):

```
years = years.Sort();
```

You also could use the `OrderBy()` method to order it and get a new List, for sample:

```
years = years.OrderBy(y => y).ToList();

// or order descending
years = years.OrderByDescending(y => y).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry but I have the compiler error: cannot convert type string to int.

Comment: I'd expect you to get a cast error for w.Year saying no implicit conversion exists between string and int (since w.Year is a string).

Comment: @Felipe-Oriani: I think you probably meant to use `int.Parse(w.Year)` instead of `(int)w.Year`, right?

Comment: You used to not be able to do type conversions in the SQL Select projection and it would result in a runtime error. In LINQ to Entities it works fine, but when querying the database directly it used to fail. I know when I need to create a new business object, I have to first execute the SQL and then use another Select to create and populate the new POCO object. If type conversion/coercion is a new feature, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

When using LINQ against the database, you're pretty limited in what you can do. But if you convert to Entities you can get much more power!

```
var years = db.tbl1
  .Select(y => y.Years)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList() // Forces the SQL query to execute and return your string list
  .Select(y => int.Parse(y.Years))
  .OrderByDescending(y => y);
```

This should execute your SQL, parse the strings to integers (seems you wanted this from your code example, if not, the ToList and second Select are unnecessary) and return a descending-ordered list of years of integer type.

Basically the queries against SQL generally can't do more powerful checks, conversions, etc. In addition, the `Select` statement is actually used as a projection to optimize the SQL query to select on the fields you want. If you need to covert the result set into a business object, you must first call ToList() (or ToArray()) to get the query to execute and return the results. Everything after that point is LinqToEntities which is much more flexible. At that point you can convert objects, create new ones, etc.

Comment: You don't want the second select in there I would think since the y in your lambda will already be `y.Years`. Also as mentioned in a comment elsewhere string sorting will be fine if all years are four digit so no need to convert to int just for sorting.

Comment: Looking at the original post I wasn't convinced Year was a numeric type. If it is, correct, you don't need the .ToList().Select(...) - it would be redundant. The OrderByDescending would then be added to the SQL query itself.

Comment: First line: "I have a database with a column: Year (nvarchar)" so I assume that Year is a string unless something strange is going on. :)

Comment: Ah - I somehow overlooked that (or read it and optimized it away).

Comment: Corrected the code sample to be explicit given the datatype and desired output type

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try also this version. :)